# I set up openGL on my visual studio but code shows errors?

Tags: visual-studio, opengl

Although the code is totally correct because it has been shared by my instructor and works fine on my university lab pcs, but when I run the code on my personal pc, it displays the error "size is ambigious":

[image: error?]

Comment: Downvoted because you attached an image and not formatted text, and the offending lines are not even visible in the image.

Comment: Well, I didn't have that much time plus it repeatedly gave the same error throughout regarding the size.

Answer (score 2):

You have declared global variable "size" and probably one (or more) of your functions use same name for parameter - this way compiler doesn't know which "size" to use. Try renaming the global variable.